# "raise oil prices" or "increase oil prices"

Tags: usage

Here is the context:

> "Most of the oil companies are planning to raise prices next year."

I know that companies can increase production, but not sure about oil prices.
Should I use "increase" instead of "raise"? Does this sentence sound natural?

Comment: What about the verb "raise" would make you suspect it might not work here?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. In order for us to answer your question, you should indicate your specific issue— why you think one word is or isn't correct— and what research you have attempted in the matter. Otherwise, this question is likely to be closed as proofreading or soliciting of opinions. After all, they could also *hike*, *boost*, *up*, *jack [up]*, *bump [up]*, *ramp [up]*, etc. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Either one is regularly used. I would say "Most oil companies are..." though.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I suppose I misunderstood the idea of this site. I  have read some questions, and I haven't found any crucial differences. They just add such phrases as "I've been thinking a lot about this problem for a long time. Some sources say that but others say that...etc". I find that useless. I wish it was allowed here to ask whether this sentence sounds natural or not etc. I'll try to comply with the rules.

Comment: Sorry) I was going to comment another post. Thank you for your answer too! I appreciate it. Yes, indeed "Most oil companies are" sounds better. And I am glad to know that both verbs are acceptable.
P.s. I am new here and in addition, I am not a native speaker)

Comment: @Truth-seeker: It *is* allowed to ask whether sentences sound natural. However, without knowing more specifics, answers are unlikely to really address whatever misunderstanding someone might have that's at the root of the question. And that's really what we're trying to do: explain things so people can apply the answers in multiple situations.

Comment: @JimReynolds I wasn't saying it is wrong, but unnecessary in my view.

Comment: I see. It really makes sense.Thank you for such detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Raise prices* and *increase prices* are both ok and natural.

Comment: However, in midwestern US, increase is considered slightly more formal